# How to send additional parameters in GRAILS JWT

Tags: grails, jwt, spring-security-rest

In Grails, as per this document (http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/#_token_generation_), in section 9.12, the JWT looks like

```
          Listing 10. JWT claims
           {
             "exp": 1422990129,
             "sub": "jimi",
              "roles": [
              "ROLE_ADMIN",
               "ROLE_USER"
           ],
           "iat": 1422986529
           }
```

How do I add/retrieve additional parameters into this JWT, for example have

```
      "device_id": 8797079079909
```

included in the claims so that, I can hash it.  Based on device id, I want to implement a logic that blacklists refresh of tokens

Thanks
UK

Comment: The answer here works: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715689/grails-rest-security-add-user-id-to-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715689/grails-rest-security-add-user-id-to-token)  I tested this in Grails `3.3.8`  adding my own custom field

Answer (score 0):

in the same documentation:
http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/next/docs/index.html

At the item:

> 11.1. Disabling bearer tokens support for full response customisation

It shows how to do it:

> If you want to render additional information in your JSON response,
>   you have to:
>
> Configure an alternative userDetailsService bean that retrieves the
>   additional information you want, and put it in a principal object.
>
> Configure an alternative accessTokenJsonRenderer that reads that
>   information from the restAuthenticationToken.principal object.

It's placed in the wrong place, I believe.

Hope this is what your're  looking for, good luck